# What is the cost of factoring polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Bronstein's: *Symbolic Integration*, here:

[image]

What is this cost of factoring in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: to factorize a huge polynomial $P(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, you have to find first one of its root, and to do this you use the Newton algorithm to estimate approximatively the localization of that root, then you use gradient descent to minimize the difference between the coefficients $P(x)$ and those of $R(x) (x-a)$ up to an arbitrary precision.

Comment: @user1952009 Approximate root finding algorithms are useless in factoring. I don't call it factoring unless you have found the roots exactly.

Comment: so what is proving there is a root in the neighborhood of $a$ and being able to calculate the value of $a$ to an arbitrary precision if it is not having found the root exactly ?